# PHPMailer - AddAttachment not working

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I have a web form which emails the form content back to me using the phpmailer function. I'm trying to add an AddAttachment feature but I seems to have an issue in the php.

This is my html snippet:

```
<td>
    <div align="right">Add attachment :</div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
</td>
```

And this is my php;

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "mailer.********.local"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = $_POST['email'];
$mail->AddAddress("frank********@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = "Request for Contract Registration for " . $_POST['name'];
$mail->Body     = "Supplier number : " . $_POST['suppno'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Payee name : " . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Address  : " . $_POST['add'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "        : " . $_POST['add2'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "             : " . $_POST['add3'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Nature of business : " . $_POST['nob'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Tax Ref : " . $_POST['rctref'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Description of works : " . $_POST['descofwks'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Start date of contract : " . $_POST['stdte'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "End date of contract : " . $_POST['enddte'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Location of contract : " . $_POST['location'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Estimated value of contract : " . $_POST['contractval'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Confirm contract : " . $_POST['confirm'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Declaration : " . $_POST['declaration'] . "\r\n";
$mail->Body     .= "Department : " . $_POST['dept'] . "\r\n";

$mail->AddAttachment($_POST['uploaded_file']);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';

    header('Location: confirm.htm');
    }
?>
```

Is there an issue with my path??? It's probally something simple that I'm missing but if anyone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it!
Thanking you in advance,
Frank.

Comment: Well you are not uploading a file - You have to learn about [uploading files (1)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) - [uploading files (2)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: You should also be using the `$_FILES` superglobal, not `$_POST` to access a posted file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
 $mail->AddAttachment($_POST['uploaded_file']); // WRONG
```

try this

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
    $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}
```

Uploaded files are stored in the temp folder.
You should add the attachment from the filesystem, it is a mistake to use $_POST for this.

Comment: I got it working. Used; if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) 
   {
            $file = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
            }

$mail->AddAttachment($file); Thanks for all your help.