# Sending attachment(s) in email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've never touched PHP, but was tasked with fixing an Intern's code..

I am trying to attach a file being uploaded to an email that I am sending. The email sends, but without the file. I am using PHPMailerAutoUpload.php (found on GitHub).

Here's the code I am using.

The attachment is being saved via `move_uploaded_file`

```
move_uploaded_file( $resume['tmp_name'] , $up_dir .basename( $random_var . '_wse_' . $resume['name'] ) )
```

Note: I have commented out the `move_uploaded_file` function to make sure I wasn't getting rid of the attachment.

```
        require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->Host = 'oursmtp';
        $mail->Port = 25;

        $mail->setFrom( $_POST['E-mail'] , $_POST['first_name'] . " " . $_POST['last_name'] );
        $mail->addAddress( 'test@test.com' );
        $mail->Subject = "Test" . @date('M/D/Y');
        $mail->msgHTML($msgDoc);

        if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
        $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                             $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        }


        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $mailError = $mail->ErrorInfo;
            $outcomeArr = array(
                                'outcome'=>'failure',
                                'message'=>'Error' . $mailError
                            );              
            echo json_encode( $outcomeArr );
            exit();             
        } else {
            // success
            $outcomeArr = array(
                                'outcome'=>'success',
                                'message'=>'Thank you'
                            );      
            echo json_encode( $outcomeArr );
        }
```

From what I have read, `$_FILES` is a temporary storage for uploaded files in PHP. With this code, the email sends, but with no attachment (only a link to the uploaded file location).

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183147/phpmailer-addattachment-not-working), but it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intern was apparently a rockstar that had no need to check for or indicate error conditions, and then mail will send even if there's no attachment or if there was an error during the upload. Change these bits to the code to tell you why the file wasn't attached:

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) && $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    if( ! $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) ) {
        echo 'Error adding attachment: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
} else if( !isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) ) {
    echo 'No uploaded file found';
} else {
    echo 'Uploaded file error: ' . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'];
}
```

Comment: Okay - Now I see that it's saying `No uploaded file found`.. Hm. That's weird. When I used the `move_uploaded_file()` method, it works, so there *should* be a file there.

Comment: It should be noted that the `uploaded_file` bit in `$_FILES['uploaded_file']` is not a static value, it is the name of the file input field in the upload form. In the original, unaltered script how is `$resume` defined? That should have the correct field name/array index.

Comment: It is defined like `Foreach($_FILES as $resume):`

Comment: That's... interesting. `var_dump($_FILES)` should tell you what array index you should be using.

Comment: Okay, good. The data it spat out is `array(1) { ["resume"]=>
  array(5) { ["name"]=> string(24) "Resume.docx ["type"]=> string(71) "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\php3F92.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(26349) } }` ... Any idea on how I reference that in the upload code?.. Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: Replace `$_FILES['uploaded_file']` with `$_FILES['resume']`

Comment: Is the `$` required before `resume`?